# AlamoFire request() only working in viewDidLoad()

Tags: alamofire, swift2

Can anyone explain why my request to a URL with the following AlamoFire request only works in my viewDidLoad() method?

```
    request(.GET, URLString: "https://mySecureUrl")
        .responseJSON { (_, _, json, error) in

                let jsonEntries = JSON(json!)
    }
```

I have added the AlamoFire swift files to my project. Whenever I add the above lines of code to any method, I never get to the code below

```
    let jsonEntries = JSON(json!)
```

The program just skips over the responseJSON altogether. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use Swift2 you must use Alamofire swift2 branch from his github : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/tree/swift-2.0

And as mentioned in the Alamofire readme, the json response is encapsulated in result parameter like this :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://httpbin.org/get")
         .responseJSON { _, _, result in
             print("Response JSON: \(result.value)")
         }
```